# Rust - How to use a synchronous and an asynchronous crate in one application

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio, rust-async-std

I began writing a program using the [Druid](https://docs.rs/druid/0.7.0/druid/) crate and [Crabler](https://docs.rs/crabler/0.1.21/crabler/) crate to make a webscraping application whose data I can explore. I only realized that merging synchronous and asynchronous programming was a bad idea long after I had spent a while building this program. What I am trying to do right now is have the scraper run while the application is open (preferably every hour).

Right now the scraper doesn't run until after the application is closed. I tried to use Tokio's `spawn` to make a separate thread that starts before the application opens, but this doesn't work because the Crabler future doesn't have the "Send" trait.

I tried to make a minimal functional program as shown below. The `title_handler` doesn't function as expected but otherwise it demonstrates the issue I'm having well.

Is it possible to allow the WebScraper to run while the application is open? If so, how?

EDIT: I tried using `task::spawn_blocking()` to run the application and it threw out a ton of errors, including that druid doesn't implement the trait `Send`.

```
use crabler::*;
use druid::widget::prelude::*;
use druid::widget::{Align, Flex, Label, TextBox};
use druid::{AppLauncher, Data, Lens, WindowDesc, WidgetExt};

const ENTRY_PREFIX: [&str; 1] = ["https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=rust&ia=web"];

// Use WebScraper trait to get each item with the ".result__title" class
#[derive(WebScraper)]
#[on_response(response_handler)]
#[on_html(".result__title", title_handler)]

struct Scraper {}

impl Scraper {
    // Print webpage status
    async fn response_handler(&self, response: Response) -> Result<()> {
        println!("Status {}", response.status);
        Ok(())
    }

    async fn title_handler(&self, _: Response, el: Element) -> Result<()> {
        // Get text of element
        let title_data = el.children();
        let title_text = title_data.first().unwrap().text().unwrap();
        println!("Result is {}", title_text);
        Ok(())
    }
}

// Run scraper to get info from https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=rust&ia=web
async fn one_scrape() -> Result<()> {
    let scraper = Scraper {};
    scraper.run(Opts::new().with_urls(ENTRY_PREFIX.to_vec()).with_threads(1)).await
}

#[derive(Clone, Data, Lens)]
struct Init {
    tag: String,
}


fn build_ui() -> impl Widget<Init> {
    // Search box
    let l_search = Label::new("Search: ");
    let tb_search = TextBox::new()
        .with_placeholder("Enter tag to search")
        .lens(Init::tag);
    let search = Flex::row()
        .with_child(l_search)
        .with_child(tb_search);

    // Describe layout of UI
    let layout = Flex::column()
        .with_child(search);
    
    Align::centered(layout)
}

#[async_std::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    // Describe the main window
    let main_window = WindowDesc::new(build_ui())
        .title("Title Tracker")
        .window_size((400.0, 400.0));

    // Create starting app state
    let init_state = Init {
        tag: String::from("#"),
    };

    // Start application
    AppLauncher::with_window(main_window)
        .launch(init_state)
        .expect("Failed to launch application");

    one_scrape().await
}
```

Comment: When using Tokio, you could use [`task::spawn_blocking()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.6.1/tokio/task/fn.spawn_blocking.html). Other async frameworks provide similar functionality.

Comment: Although `spawn_blocking` is intended for interfacing with terminating synchronous tasks. To have a long-running thread which lives mostly independently from the async runtime (which seems to be the case here? it's not entirely clear), the regular `spawn` is usually the recommendation.